# How can I use re.search('.*txt', ) like perl, in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I googled it and read the docs but couldn't understand so how should I do it.

I want to check if the string exists as a text file.

So, I tried using re.search('*.txt', string) in python.

but '*.txt' is error. (when I change it 'txt', it's working but it can be a file name not as a file type)

So how should I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you tried or how it failed. Can you post both a stripped-down, runnable example that demonstrates the error, and the stack trace of the error it produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
 re.search(".*\.txt$", "hello.txt")
```

meaning match (.*) whatever you want, then a dot (.), then at the end match "txt".

Comment: If using the regex route then there's no need to specify the leading `.*` - just `\.txt$` is sufficient when using `re.search`

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that i should put '.' in front of *.txt.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I just blindly translated it.

Answer (score 2):

Too much work.

```
S.endswith('.txt')
```